# Question about the characteristic subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a group. A subgroup  H is called characteristic if $f(H)\subset H$ for all auto morphism $f$ of G.Pick out true statements.

(a) Every characteristic subgroup is normal.

(b) Every normal subgroup is characteristic.

(c) if $N$ is normal subgroup of a group G and M be a characteristic subgroup of N then M is normal subgroup of G.

Answer (score 1):

Hint on a):

A subgroup $H$ is normal if $f(H)\subset H$ is true for each *inner* automorphism.

Answer (score 1):

For the last one:

Consider the automorphism $$\phi: N\to N,~~x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$$ Since $M~\text{char}~ N$ so $M^{\phi}=M$ and so...

Comment: @amWhy: Hi Amy. Nice to see you here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

a) True.  For $g \in G$, we use $f:G \rightarrow G$ defined by $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}.$

b) Wrong.  Example $G=\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$. Choose $H = \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus 0$ 
and $f(x,y)=(y,x)$

c) True. For $g \in G$, we can choose $f:N \rightarrow N$ defined by $x\mapsto gxg^{-1} $ because $N$ is normal of $G.$
Let $m \in M$. Then $gmg^{-1}=f(m) \in M.$